# Find the derivative of f at point P in the direction of vector u.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

> Find the derivative of $f$ at point $(18,9)$ in direction of $\left<7,2\right>$.
>   $$f(x,y) = \arctan \left(\frac{2y}{x} \right) + 3\arcsin\left( \frac{xy}{324} \right)$$

For this I got $0.131317$, but my answer is wrong.

This is what I did:

Gradient of f:
$$\nabla f = \left<0.068,0.24\right>$$

Then I found the unit vector of:
$$\left<7,2\right> = \left<\frac{7}{\sqrt{53}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{53}}\right>$$

Then I did the dot product:

$$\left<0.068,0.24\right> \cdot \left<\frac{7}{\sqrt{53}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{53}}\right> = 0.131317$$

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? My homework says the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Fixing LaTeX formatting.

Comment: @Elsa So that others don't have to fix your formatting in the future, here are some of the things that might be helpful to you: `$\sqrt{blah}$` produces $\sqrt{blah}$, `$\arctan\left( \frac{blah}{blah}\right)$` produces $\arctan\left( \frac{blah}{blah}\right)$, `$\langle blah, blah \rangle$` produces $\langle blah, blah \rangle$, and `$\langle blah, blah\rangle \cdot \langle other, blah \rangle$` produces $\langle blah, blah\rangle \cdot \langle other, blah \rangle$.  More info can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Bye_World thanks! ok

Comment: Assuming that you calculated $\nabla f(P)$ correctly and whatever the unit vector $u$ maybe, you calculated $\nabla f(P) \cdot u$. Perhaps they were looking for a unit vector representation from $P$ toward $(7,2)$.

Comment: WolframAlpha is getting the same answer as you at each step.  Perhaps you didn't keep enough sig figs?

Comment: @MathNewbie i did find the unit vector and i did the dot product. what do u mean unit vector representation?

Comment: @Bye_World ya i know i checked too! idk what to do? my hw likes up to 3 numbers after the decimal, so i dont think that is the issue?

Comment: For instance, you have $(7,2) - P$ is the direction you actually want (then normalize it). If you look at several problems in your calculus textbook in the directional derivative section, you'll see that they want this. I'm just saying that maybe the question want this (just a thought).